# Charles proxy doesn't work with Android One Xiaomi a1

Tags: android, ssl, proxy, charles-proxy

I'm trying to proxy traffic from the phone with Android One - Xiaomi a1. I installed the certificate, allowed these certificates everywhere in the settings, enabled SSL proxying in the Charles itself for the specified domain.

**But every time the traffic starts to go through the Charles, all SSL connections have an error**:

> Failure SSLHandshake: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown

I put the certificate on both Wifi and VPN connections, re-downloaded and deleted it again several times, etc. Now, I still do not understand why it does not work. On another Android devices, everything works fine, even on an iPhone everything is ok...

Answer (score 0):

In Android Nougat, Android handles trusted certificate authorities (CAs) to provide safer defaults for secure app traffic, user added CA will invoke SSLHandshake failure. you can check [this blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/changes-to-trusted-certificate.html) for more infomation